# javascript - using if statement for multiple conditions vs switch case

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I want to write something along the lines of this to check the page urls for a string.

```
url example 1 - http://something.com/else/apples
url example 2 - http://something.com/else/oranges
url example 3 - http://something.com/else/bananas
...
url example 10 - http://something.com/else/kiwis
```

pseudo code:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('apples')>-1)
{
    alert('apples');
}
if(window.location.href.indexOf('oranges')>-1)
{
    alert('oranges');
}
....
```

As you can see it looks rather ugly to have multiple if statements so I'm looking for some advice on how to achieve this using a single if statement or possible a switch case. I had an idea about an if statement with several 'OR' statements, but I'm not sure if that's the best way of going about with this.

Thank you

Comment: What if you get the end of the url and put that in the alert? That way you have no `if`s at all. Edit: Chris already made a one-liner solution.

Comment: If you intend to perform the same action regardless of the string, as implied by your example, then create a function that accepts the string to search for.  That way you only need it once. No switch or multiple if statements.

Comment: Yes I intend to perform the same action, but would the string look something like this? '/something/apples, /something-else/bananas, /other/fruits'

Comment: `switch` acts the same as `if` it is used to **increase** readability of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let urls = ["url1.com", "url2.com"]

urls.forEach((url) => {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(url) > -1) {
        alert("Do something")
    }
})
```

The idea is to use an array instead of many variables, and to loop through its items with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];

var link = window.location.href.split("/").pop();

if (fruits.includes(link)) {
   alert(link);
}
```

Comment: Be careful with that, `.includes` is an ES7 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
alert(window.location.href.split("/").pop());
```

This takes whatever comes after the last `/` and alerts that. Of course, this will alert *anything*. If there is a "whitelist" of things to alert, then @Purefan might have a better solution. This is just the quick-'n-easy solution.

Comment: This isn't what it was asked for.

Comment: @Erazihel, it kind of is actually. It will always alert the last bit of the URL which is basically what OP does. However, as I explain, **if** there are scenarios a URL might not contain a fruit or whatever, then Purefan has the better solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the alert is a pure example in place of the actual code. So your code has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, okay so you just put that in a variable and use that instead in the "actual code". I don't see the problem?

Comment: @Purefan has a solution than answer perfectly the needs of OP. Your answer is clearly invalid. You should delete it.

Comment: I'm starting to warm toward @Purefan's solution :)

Comment: @Erazihel, **invalid**? It's clearly just another approach. It may very well not be suitable for OP's intention, but it doesn't make it **invalid**. If you have a problem with it, go ahead and flag it.

Comment: @user5396759, that's totally fine. Expected even. As I explained in the answer, this is only a basic one-liner... not sure why everyone got so upset about it. It's clearly on-topic...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output specific information based on what the URL says, then I would suggest maybe using JSON to get information quickly. This will allow you to avoid having to use a loop or any conditional statements, and you can essentially get any information you want. That information can even contain an HTML page/element to be loaded in -

```js
var pageInfo = {
  "apple": "some info about apples",
  "orange": "some other info about oranges",
  "banana": "more banana information"
}

var urlPage = window.location.href.split("/").pop();

var info = pageInfo[urlPage];

//to test -
console.log(pageInfo["apple"]);
console.log(pageInfo["orange"]);
console.log(pageInfo["banana"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is map specific values to specific outcomes. You can do this with an actual map. You can associate anything to values in a map, even functions. Then, use your favorite way to loop across the object. Here's a silly example:

```
var fruitMap = {
  'oranges': 'I don\'t like those.',
  'apples': 'Three a day keeps the doctor away.'
};

for (var fruit in fruitMap) {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf(fruit) > -1) {
    alert(fruitMap[fruit]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch` acts the same as `if` it is used to **increase** readability of code

```js
$('#fruit').keyup(function() {

  var c = $(this).val();
  var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'orange', 'raspberry', 'strawberry', 'wildberry', 'cranberry', 'blueberry', 'limone', 'grapefruit', 'kiwi', 'mango'];

  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    switch (c) {
      case fruits[i]:
        console.log(fruits[i]);
        break;
      default:
        '';
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter a fruit: <input type="text" id="fruit">
```